# CheckedTextView doesnt Toggle

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, checkedtextview

I have a custom listview that has CheckedTextView. When i click the the items it doesn't toggle the checked state of the object and reflect in the ui.

dialog_categories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
    android:background="@color/primary_white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/dialog_category_title"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_color"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dialog_category_checkbox"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_color" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="6dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_category_ok"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dialog_category_btn_ok"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

dialog_list_item_category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/categories_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick="toggle"
        android:text="sss" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CategoriesDialogFragment.java

```
public class CategoriesDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
    CheckBox checkAll;
    ListView categoriesListView;
    CategoriesListAdapter adapter;
    static Category category;

    String[] categories = new String[] { "Hill Station", "Beach", "Historic",
            "Wild Life", "Waterfall", "River", "Archeology" };
    String[] categories_state = new String[] { "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1",
            "0" };

    public static CategoriesDialogFragment newInstance() {
        CategoriesDialogFragment frag = new CategoriesDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_categories);

        categoriesListView = (ListView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.listViewDialog);

        List<Category> theCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            Category pl = new Category(categories[i], false);
            theCategories.add(pl);
        }

        categoriesListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        adapter = new CategoriesListAdapter(MainActivity.context,
                R.layout.dialog_list_item_category, theCategories);

        categoriesListView.setAdapter(adapter);


        checkAll = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAll);
        checkAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.context, "Check",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (isChecked) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        category = adapter.getItem(i);
                        category.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        category = adapter.getItem(i);
                        category.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });
        return dialog;

    }

    private static class CategoriesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {
        public Context mContext;

        List<Category> mCategories;

        public CategoriesListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                List<Category> categories) {
            super(context, resource, categories);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mCategories = categories;
            this.mContext = context;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mCategories.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Category getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mCategories.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater viewInflater;
                viewInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = viewInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.dialog_list_item_category, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.categoryName = (CheckedTextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.categories_checkbox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.categoryName.setText(mCategories.get(position)
                    .getCategoryName());

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            CheckedTextView categoryName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap the `CheckedTextView` in a `RelativeLayout`, remove the wrapper `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Luksprog wow that worked. wondering why the check and uncheck is related to that.

Comment: @Luksprog i have a CheckAll button which i want to check/uncheck all items based on the state. any idea how it can be done ?

Comment: The row need to be `Checkable`(implements the interface) and the wrapper(the `RelativeLayout`) isn't Checkable. *any idea how it can be done ?* - in the `getView` method you need to set the checked status of the *categories_checkbox* `CheckedTextView` depending on the state you store(and modify) in the `Category` items.

Comment: @Luksprog when i try to do holder.categoryName.setChecked(true); it still doesnt reflect the checked state. i am adding this in the getView()

Comment: @Luksprog i have posted a seperate question with relevant changes to the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137760/checkedtextview-oncheckedchangelistener-with-notifydatasetchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` instead of `dialog_list_item_category.xml`?

**Update:** @Luksprog's comment is the solution: Remove the `RelativeLayout` and it works just like with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`.

Comment: i have done this categoriesListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

Answer (score 1):

Are You using the proper xml?
There's 
         dialog_list_item_categories.xml 
but in your code You use everywhere 
R.layout.dialog_list_item_category

Comment: sorry that was a typo when writing the question