# CheckedTextView won't remove the checkMark icon when status false

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I have a `listview` with `CheckedTextViews` as records, when clicking on an item I can see that the status of the `CheckedTextView` has switched but the `Checkmark` is never hide.

This is my XML of the listView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listFilters"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
```

and this is the XML of the records :

```
<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:text="filter1"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/icon_blue_checkmark" />
```

This is my `OnItemClick Listener :`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Filter filter = (Filter) adapter.getItem (position);
    boolean isSelected = !filter.isSelected ();
    filter.setSelected (isSelected);

    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)listView.getChildAt (position);
    ctv.toggle ();

    // shows that the status of the CheckedTextView has switched successfully
    Toast.makeText (
        getActivity (),
        "CheckedTextView status : " + ctv.isChecked (),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

**EDIT :** 
I have just noticed that when replacing my custom checkmark drawable with : `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"` It works fine. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure your `onItemClick` is getting called?

Comment: Yes, the `toast` is shown successfully with the right status of the `CheckedTextView`

Comment: @karaokyo : forget about the adapter initialization part, I was wrong in it my bad. But the onClick issue is correct.

Comment: In response to your edit: what is `icon_blue_checkmark`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter);
ctv.toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` when declaring the adapter as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14136476/9320774)